# pros and cons of different Dbconnectors approach in c#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Anyone please tell me what are the pros and cons of using these approaches?

```
1-SqlDataAdapters
2-ADO
3-DAO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at 
[Data Access Practices Using Microsoft .Net: A Nerdly Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff707264).